# Cannot open source file in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to compile [OBS studio](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio) with [this tutorial](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions) in windows using Visual Studio Community 2015. I have created a project in visual studio and copied the entire git repo into the project by dragging the files into the solution explorer. This project has dependencies on libav, x264, and curl. They are given as .lib, .dll, and header files.

The problem is I keep getting "cannot open source file". I have the the header files in a separate folder from the dll's and lib's (dll and lib are in the same folder). Under the project settings->VC++ Directories I added the include directory, and also added the library directory. Then I added the lib's specifically under Linker->input->additional Dependencies. Then I added the directory that contains the .dll files to the environment variable PATH.

After all this, I still keep getting the same error, as well as a few other errors. Here is a screen shot of one source file that has the issue.

[image: cannot open source file]

These are my settings.

[image: Directories]

[image: Libraries]

[image]

For the path, I have tried with and without the trailing forward slash.

Comment: Make sure you are changing project setting for the same configuration as you build. I see Debug/Win32 and Debug/x86. Not sure if those the same. Check that include folder contain *folder* that is before `/` in the `#include` clause and this folder contain a *file* that you include. Physically. I mean go there and see if those exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT:
Use the C/C++ settings instead of VC++ settings for additional include directories.

What is probably holding you up is that those folder icons in the VS sidebar are not actually related to the file system.  They are filters and don't change depending on the actual directory.

This is another explanation for Drop's suggestion -- check to see if the files are really where you think they are.

Comment: The header files are there relative to the path I put in the include directory. Visual studio find them and opens then aswell. Since these are libraries, there is no source code. This is why I'm a bit lost as to how correctly implement them. The lib and DLL files are not named exactly like the header files either so this also adds to my confusion.

Comment: Your errors now have nothing to do with the .lib or .dll (as of yet).  You may try using the C/C++ instead of VC++ for additional includes.  You could also try including the directories using "" instead of <>.

Comment: I have found the problem. I just had to add the additional directories to C/C++ and linker rather than "VC++ Directories", just as you said. If you could change the answer to reflect that so i can accept it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I already added the include libraries but that was not enough.  The error went away once I switched the configuration from `x86` to `x64` in Project Properties.

Comment: Same here. An MS classic!